# wire crimper sizes: mm2 vs AWG

Tags: wire, crimp, awg

Electrical wire crimpers available on Amazon Canada tend to list die sizes in mm2.   [This one](https://www.amazon.ca/Mophorn-Hydraulic-Terminal-Electrical-Crimping/dp/B01LY7NTB2/ref=pd_sbs_469_6?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01LY7NTB2&pd_rd_r=c3b30da8-908d-11e8-bb65-89337eb223e8&pd_rd_w=44bga&pd_rd_wg=XjsqD&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_p=7452810999151854150&pf_rd_r=XGDTRV9F81NTZKME0G0N&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&psc=1&refRID=XGDTRV9F81NTZKME0G0N) cross-lists them in AWG, but there are some discrepancies between these sizes and the [mm2 equivalent of those AWG sizes](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/wire/awg-to-mm.html).

```
die size (mm2)  listed AWG     AWG equivalent in mm2
----------------------------------------------------
16              6AWG           13.3
25              4AWG           21.2
35              2AWG           33.6
50              1/0AWG         53.5
70              2/0AWG         67.4
95              3/0AWG         85.0
120             4/0 - 250 MCM  107.2
```

Why is there such a large discrepancy?  Will this tool actually be usable for crimping wire of standard AWG thickness?  Other tools listed on Amazon also include this same set of die sizes (or a super- or sub-set).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the discrepancy is that the AWG equivalent CSA you have found is solid wire. This type of wire carries the maximum current for CSA but also has the maximum bend radius.

A tradeoff between current carrying capability for a lower bend radius is achieved by stranding the wire, i.e. 12AWG (2.1mm sq.) could actually be 37 x 28AWG and the new diameter (due to spacing between the 28AWG strands) is 2.9mm sq.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/awg-wire-gauge-d_731.html

[44 Spec Wire](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/418/NG_CD_44A0111_P1-665852.pdf)

Comment: If that's the case, why isn't the die size a consistent amount or percentage larger than the AWG equivalent?  the 70mm2 die size is meant to correspond to an AWG with area 67.4, but the 95 is meant to match AWG with area 85.  The 50 mm2 die size is actually smaller than its AWG equivalent of 53.5.

Comment: Remember your dies are hexagonal. So whilst the area will match, the flat sides of the hexagon at their centrepoints will have a shorter radius than their equivalent circular area.

Comment: They need to crush the wires somewhat to achieve a solid crimp connection.

Answer (score 0):

Because the crimp is bigger than the solid core wire.  If you crimp a connector onto a wire, the connector itself is made of sheet metal and it adds substantially to the cross sectional size.  The gauge of just the connector sheet metal is substantial.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really answer the second part of the question, maybe ask the manufacturer.

As for the discrepancy:

6 AWG is equal to a crossectional area of 13.3mm2. Now, have a look at the [international wire sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60228):

There's only 10mm2 and 16mm2, you can't get a wire labeled 13.3mm2*, so the convention seems to be to equate 6AWG to 16mm2.

The cables are indeed of different sizes.

If you are US based, you probably will have access to AWG wire's, so get a tool for AWG crimping. Can't really recommend a specific one here.

*at least I haven't seen those in Germany yet